# Ideas on reveal part of back view with iOS and swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, swrevealviewcontroller

I'm not sure if the title of this question fits. But below is what I want to achieve.
I try to implement a UI design, where on the top layer is a UITableView, and the back layer is a UIView.  When the cell on the UITableView is tapped, it will reveal the UIView.  Here is the tricky part, I would like the UITableView to slide to the right and reveal 2/3 of the UIView. So it will be 2/3 of the screen from the left is the UIView, 1/3 of the screen is the UITableView.
Here is a screen of what I was talking about.[image][image]
I tried SWRevealViewController, but it is not exactly what I want.
1. When I tap on the cell, nothing happens. But I was able to use `panGesture` to drag the UITableView to the right and reveal 2/3 of the back UIView.
2. If I link a segue from the cell to the UIView in stroyboard, when I tap on the cell, it will just reveal the whole UIView.

I would appreciate some ideas and point me at the right directions.

Comment: You just need to adjust the leading and trailing constraints of your tableview to push it offscreen

Comment: @Paulw11 I'm not sure how I can achieve what you suggested, I would appreciate if you could show me a quick example.

Comment: It is hard to show quickly. Basically you would have your background view and your tableview in the same view controller, with the tableview on top.  You can created @IBOutlet references to constraints, so you can get the reference for the table views leading and trailing constraint.  Then when a row is selected you can modify the `constant` property of the two constraints to move the tableview off screen

Comment: @Paulw11 I tried your method, and it works.  If you could, please make your comment an answer. I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

There's one way you can do this is to add the UITableView on top of the UIView.

First, add the UIView at the back (maybe default it as the first one).
Then, add the UITableView on top of the UIView, like this.

```
yourUIView.frame = self.view.frame;
self.view.addSubview(yourUIView);

yourUITableView.frame = self.view.frame;
self.view.addSubview(yourUITableView);
```

After, you select a cell, animate the UITableView to the 2/3 of the screen.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) { 
    yourUITableView.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/3*2, 0, yourUITableView.frame.size.width, yourUITableView.frame.size.height);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

You can use the constraint and play with the table view as expected.

Comment: But this can only set the constraint once, correct? Then I'm not sure how this can relate to what I want to achieve.

Comment: have an outlet for this constraint and change the constant value to move the table view dynamically